# gcc cannot find -lglfw3 && i was unable to add the path

Tags: c, gcc, glfw

I am running CentOS 6.4, I have just installed GLFW 3.0.4 for some software package for CFD L-B visualisation. That's not my issue, the issue is that I was following instructions to test of GLFW was installed properly, I ran into some issues.

I began by

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

Which has outputted `main.o` file, and went onto run this with the help of advice of another thread :

```
g++ main.o  -o main.exec  `pkg-config --libs glfw3` -lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldlD
```

which has then given me this error code:

```
Package glfw3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glfw3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glfw3' found
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Have tried adding `-L` or `-B` to the path of `glfw3.pc` and no use,

Can you please advise on how I can get this to work properly?

Comment: The linker `ld` is telling you clearly it cannot find `libglfw3`. `pkg-config` is telling you clearly it didn't find `glfw3.pc` in the pkg-config search path. That tells you your *linker search path* `-L/path/to/libglfw3` isn't defined (or it's not at that path) and no `glfw3.pc` tells you the same regarding the pkg-config search path. Taken together, the most likely cause is **you don't have `libglfw3` installed.** Verify you have that package installed and then look at the file list for that package to determine where the files are installed after you install it.

Comment: Thanks David for your prompt reply, Actually I have found where the `glfw3.pc` exists, and it is in the `pkg-config` file, as well as I have `libglfw.so.3`, `libglfw.so.3.0`, and `libglfw.so` all installed in the folder called `lib` just above the `pkg-config` folder. I was just struggling with the correct syntax to add the paths correctly sudo code for it to run correctly can you please advise?

Comment: Check to make sure the `/path/to/your/.pc_file` is in the pkg-config search path, e.g. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, you can check with `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`. The defaults (on Linux) are `/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig` (unless your distro does something different). You can use a one-shot `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH};/path/to/your/.pc_file g++ main.o  -o main.exec...`